# What could be causing this viewport shading issue?

Tags: 3d-view

How it looks:

[image: Shading]

It does appear only under certain angles:

[image: Shading]

but it also appears on darkly shaded faces.

This is in edit mode with no materials in the default solid shading mode. I am also 100% that I don't have a duplicated mesh, normals are fine and I have no modifiers.

I never noticed anything similar in previous versions. But I have also changed my computer since then, from an Intel/Nvidia setup to Amd/Amd. Could that be the issue?

Blender version: 3.0.0, branch: master, commit date: 2021-12-02 18:35, hash: f1cca3055776, type: release

Comment: it looks like overlapping faces but you say it's not the case? maybe share your file?

Comment: @moonboots this happens in all files, I can make a brand new file, plonk down a plane and enter edit mode: https://imgur.com/a/hFGqdwN

Comment: It's also a fresh install on a new computer.

Comment: Did you set 'Smooth shading' for your object?

Comment: @eezacque No, I think it's pretty clear from the images that it's not smooth shaded.

Comment: so it may be a driver problem, it seems to occur with the last drivers of AMD

Comment: @moonboots It's seems you're about right, did a bit of searching and found [this](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-rad-win-21-40-beta-blender-3-0) which seems to indicate that the current "regular" drivers aren't quite okay for Blender.

Comment: And after installing the beta drivers for Blender 3.0 the issue is gone!